# Could someone kindly scan the word "idiot" for me, please?

Tags: poetry

Three syllables or two?

I mean, YES, it is three: officially. So the dictionary says.

Still, how would you scan it in an iambic line? Or would it make a good trochee?

Comment: Idiots come with their paperback novels to bore us to tears with their garrulous speeches of nothing at all. Surely it's a dactyl.

Comment: It depends on your accent/dialect.  Many an Irishman would say ‘eedyot’.  But, as Andrew Leach says, in general it is  dactyl.  Though in Shakespeare’s Scottish play, Macbeth says:

Comment: Oops, slip of the thumb.  “... It <life> is a tale / Told by an idiot, full of sound and fury / Signifying nothing.”. Try scanning that!

Comment: Depends on the poem

Comment: As might be inferred from @Tuffy's comment, Shakespeare seems to have treated *idiot* as a trochee whenever he used it—two syllables with the accent on the first syllable. Robert Bridges, in his poem *To Catullus* has the line *A rank musk-idiot, the filthiest skunk*. This poem is in iambic pentameter, so *idiot* needs to be an amphimacer, with a stress on the first and last syllable. In real life it's a dactyl, but dactyls don't fit well into iambic meter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may scan as either two or three syllables, according to the requirements of the meter.

If two syllables, the beat is on the 1st syllable.

If three syllables, the beat's are on the 1st & 3rd syllables, assuming it's a line of iambic meter. The 3rd syllable is destressed, but it is still a beat.

In this post I explain the principles by which words can be expanded, contracted or glided together: https://versemeter.wordpress.com/

Another thing to clarify is that although "idiot" scanned as two syllables is a trochaic *word*, that doesn't automatically make it a trochaic *foot* within a line of verse, as trochaic words and phrases frequently *span the foot divisions*. This is something I explore in the second half of this post: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-iambic-and-trochaic-meters/answer/Keir-Fabian

In this post I provide a thorough explanation of the technical principles of iambic meter: https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-good-way-to-check-iambic-pentameter/answer/Keir-Fabian?share=01ae6686&srid=LqSx

Comment: IMHO, "idiot" is *usually* three syllables--"id-i-ot", but it can be just two, as "ih-jut" or "id-yot".  You can take your choice.

Comment: For metrical purposes it can just as easily count as either two or three.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. This community does things a little differently from other Q&A sites, mostly stemming from Stack Exchange’s intention to be a long-term repository of information. It’s customary here to block-quote relevant excerpts (and cite them, as you have done) so that in the event the external link breaks or changes, the answers still stand on their own here.